# innerHtml not render html tag

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I'm on working with `[innerHtml]` in Angular and I wrote a function to render table body from data.

My function:

```
 renderTableBody() {
    let htmlString = '';

    this.dataContent.forEach((row: any) => {
        htmlString += '<tr>';
        this.dataTableConfig.forEach((item: any) => {
            var x = item.field;
            htmlString += `<td>${row[item.field]}</td>`;
        });

        htmlString += '</tr>';
    });

    console.log(htmlString);
    return htmlString;
}
```

My template:

```
<table class="table datatable-basic table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let item of dataTableConfig">{{ item.header }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody [innerHTML]="renderTableBody()"></tbody>
    </table>
```

But it just renders the data content without the `<tr>` or `<td>` tag:

[image: A string of content shown as a text node which is the first child of a tbody element. A tr element is the second and final child of the tbody element.]

I also `console.log()` the value to check and the value in the console looks right.

[image: A string containing HTML elements shown in the console tab of the Chrome Developer Tools]

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please update your post to include your code. See:  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why are you building an HTML string instead of using `*ngFor` in your template? `*ngFor` is the correct way to dynamically create elements based on some collection in your component.

Comment: Binding `[innerHTML]` to a function like you're suggesting will rebuild the string and cause the table to rerender each change detection cycle which is very inefficient. `*ngFor` does not suffer from the same issue and will (mostly) only rerender the table when the bound collection changes.

Comment: Further all have been said (don't use innerHTML if you can use tags in your component else *ngFor/*ngIf), when you use innerHTML you should use [DomSanitizer] (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) and equal a variable using `this.variable=this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(..your text..)`,

Comment: Hi @DM, the reason I used `[innerHtml]` is I want to make it more dynamic and handle it with many attributes in Typescript is easier than Html. Have a good day!

Comment: @liz, I don't agree with your sentence: "I want to make it more dynamic and handle it with many attributes". You always can to have yours "items" as `{field:..,class:...,data:...}` and use, e.g. `<td [attr.data-data]="item.data" [class]="item.class">{{item.field}}</td>`. Angular work better "thinking in variables". But I'm happy you solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, its not recommended to call a function directly inside a template as it results in calling that function again and again due to the change detection cycle https://angular.io/guide/change-detection.

Instead, use the below format if possible.

HTML:

```
<tbody>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let row of dataContent">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of dataTableConfig">
            <td>{{row[item?.Field]}}</td>
        </tr>
     </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

TS:

```
let dataContent: any[] = [//...some data];
let dataTableConfig: any[] = [//...some data];
```

by doing so, you can achieve the same result, in angular way!

edit 1:

I mistakenly left a space {{row[item?. Field]}}.
It should be {{row[item?. Field]}}

edit 2:

If both dataContent and dataTableConfig have same data, you could shorten the template by

```
 <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let row of dataContent">
       <td>{{row?.name}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

If both are different set of data, and needs to be shown based/dependent on each other, say for ex:

```
 let dataContent = [
   {name: "liz", age: 20},
   {name: "foo", age: 25}
 ]; 

 let dataTableConfig = [
    {name: "liz", department: "IT", country: "USA"},
    {name: "foo", department: "Tester", country: "Australia"}
 ];

 let combinedArray = this.dataContent.map((x) => {
    const matchedName = this.dataTableConfig.find((y) => y.name === x.name);
    return matchedName ? {...x, ...matchedName } : x;
 });

 <tbody>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let element of combinedArray ">
       <td>{{element?.name}} - {{element?.department}}</td>
   </ng-container>
 </tbody>
```

This way you handle the core logic in your component.ts file and just render the manipulated data in HTML.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much.
There's some thing wrong with variable binding in `<td>{{row[item?. Field]}}</td>`.
Do you have any other suggestions or the keywords about this case for me to research.

Comment: Hi, could you share the interface of "row" and "item"? If "row" is an object/array, then the above piece of code which I shared will work. If "row" is a string, then of course my code will fail.

Comment: Hi, both `dataContent` and `dataTableConfig` is a list object like `[ { name: 'liz', age: '18' },{ name: 'liz1', age: '18' },]`, that's just an example.

Comment: Hey I just edited my answer, check whether it resolves your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry for not saying clearly, make you mistaken. `dataTableConfig = [{ headerName: 'Votes', width: '120px' },{ headerName: 'FullName', width: '120px' },];
    dataContent = [{ Votes: '1', FullName: 'Tung nguyen' },{ Votes: '3', FullName: 'Administrator' },{ Votes: '5', FullName: 'foo' },]`. In there, `dataTableConfig` contains header column name, some attributes and `dataContent` contains table content.
But base on your answer I resolve my issue. Many thanks, have a great day.